# How do i fix this buffer overflow issue?

Tags: c++, winapi, stdvector

I recently ran a code scan on a project i'm working on using HP fortify.
It reported that I have a critical issue with ReadFile.
I never pass an empty buffer.
Any suggestions on how to fix the potential buffer overflow problem.

**The Abstract**

The function Read() in serialport.cpp might be able to write outside the bounds of allocated memory on line 225, which could corrupt data, cause the program to crash, or lead to the execution of malicious code.

```
DWORD serialport::Read(std::vector<char> & buffer)
{
    DWORD read = 0;
    int val = ReadFile(h, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), &read, NULL);

    if (val == 0)
    {
        LPCSTR ptr = "";
        PrintError(ptr);
    }

    buffer.resize(read);
    return read;
}
```

Comment: To me, ReadFile looks ok, but PrintError seems to be not being passed a handle https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms708391(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As a side note; you may wish to consider the case where someone passes in a buffer of size 0

Comment: *I never pass an empty buffer* -- Then in production, an empty buffer *is* passed.  Oops.

Comment: The return value 0 (FALSE) of `ReadFile` does not indicate failure. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm not seeing an overflow on the ReadFile. Maybe put a comment marking which one exactly is line 225. It's possibly overzealous reporting because you didn't actually check buffer.size(), so whether or not you pass an empty buffer isn't really relevant to whether or not this function itself is good.

Comment: The behavior is undefined if the vector is empty and you use it in ReadFile using `&buffer[0]`.  Use `buffer.data()` instead.

Comment: You do return an empty buffer, and Read tends to be called repeatedly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *if the vector is empty* - `buffer.size()` will be 0 and in this case to which point `&buffer[0]` irrelevant. `ReadFile` simply return true and `read` bytes will be 0

Comment: @RbMm -- Do you have the source to `ReadFile`?  If not, we don't know exactly what is being done with that second parameter, regardless if nothing is read from the file.  Believe me, I have had experience with MS engineers directly with an API function, and they plainly (and rightly) state -- don't assume something will be done if it isn't documented.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i replaced the code with. int val = ReadFile(h, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &read, NULL); and i still get a buffer overflow error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - src also exist in wdk and fastfat. we clear say that `nNumberOfBytesToRead` is 0. so buffere have 0 size and it will be not accessed

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez -- Well, you asked for suggestions on fixing the error, and I gave one.  Otherwise we're just playing a game trying to make a tool act in the way we want it to act.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek - *0 does not indicate failure* - in synchronous io case - indicate. and here used synchronous io, because *lpOverlapped* is 0 (otherwise (use 0  *lpOverlapped*  for async io) this is critical bug)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How is `buffer.data()` better than `&buffer[0]` in preventing undefined behaviour if the vector is empty?

Comment: @zett42 -- If the vector is empty, `buffer[0]` is invalid. So you're asking for the address of something that is invalid when you state `&buffer[0]`.  With `buffer.data()`, you're calling a member function that can react accordingly if the buffer is empty (in this case, will return `nullptr`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ["_If size() is 0, data() may or may not return a null pointer._"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). Even if it would always return `nullptr`, the `lpBuffer` parameter of `ReadFile()` is not optional, so you are not allowed to pass `nullptr`.

Comment: @zett42 if the *nNumberOfBytesToRead* parameter of ReadFile() is 0 - the nullptr in place *lpBuffer* will be valid, simply because system will not access data of this buffer (it size is 0) and it is "ideal" aligned (for case non cached io and device require buffer align more than 1 byte). however no sense at all call `ReadFile` with 0 bytes, especially when we return number of readed bytes. can simply return 0 in this case

Answer (score 0):

> I never pass an empty buffer

But someone else may someday. You're making the mistake of evaluating the code inside the function with knowledge of what you do outside the function. That function **can** be passed an empty `std::vector<char> &`. Someday, it *will* be. Handle that case.

Comment: Not to mention the bad practice of resizing the buffer that got passed in, nobody will expect that.

Comment: This answer doesn't even try to explain *why* passing an empty buffer is supposed to be a problem. Sorry, that's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You never pass an empty buffer, but the code scanning tool doesn't know that.  The ones I've worked with look only at individual functions, so it will assume the actual arguments can be anything.

If the buffer is empty, then `&buffer[0]` is undefined behavior.  You've tried to create a pointer to memory that doesn't exist.  That's probably what the code scanning tool is reacting to.

Even though `&buffer[0]` is an invalid pointer, you might expect nothing to go wrong because nothing will access it.  But `buffer[0]` is itself an invalid access, even though you're not reading or writing to that element.

Although you might get away with using `buffer.data()` instead, I'd still be wary of it.  It only seems to be defined for a non-empty array.

To fix the problem, ...

Option 1:  Add `assert(!buffer.empty());` to the beginning of the function.

Option 2:  Get the pointer more carefully,

```
DWORD read = 0;
char trash;
void *pBuffer = buffer.empty() ? &trash : buffer.data();
int val = ReadFile(h, pBuffer, buffer.size(), &read, NULL);
```

Although the tool didn't complain, I'd also make sure that `buffer.size()` (a `std::size_t`) fits into a DWORD, which might not be the case in a 64-bit build.

Comment: If the buffer is empty, then `buffer.size()==0`. when we pass 0 as buffer size system will not access this buffer. the value of buffer pointer will play role only in case not cached io and device require buffer align more than 1 byte

Comment: Option 1 - `assert()` is good as a debugging tool but it doesn't replace proper error handling. IMO passing a buffer size of 0 is an exceptional condition, so it should be reported as such, by throwing an exception. Now we have actual error handling for release builds too and the `assert()` can be removed as it works for debug builds aswell.

Comment: @zett42 - despite read 0 bytes is error by sense in most case, formal this is not error. the `[&buffer[0], &buffer[0]+buffer.size())`always a valid range when `buffer.size()==0`. empty range - valid range. not think need trow exception here

Comment: @RbMm Sure. But it can be assumed, if someone passes empty buffer to such function, it is a programming (logic) error. Why should someone ask for 0 bytes, it doesn't make sense. So by throwing an exception we make sure that the developer notices his error and can't ignore it.

Comment: @RbMm:  `buffer[0]` returns a reference to the first element in the buffer.  If that element doesn't exist, it's undefined behavior even if you don't try to read or write to that element.  The problem occurs _before_ the call to ReadFile, so the fact that the size argument is 0 is irrelevant.  MS's `std::vector` implementation will assert "vector subscript out of range" in debug builds.

Comment: if this construct `&buffer[0]` yourself can case exception, etc - yes (i not familiar with  std::vector), but if it return, even random value - call to `ReadFile` will be ok even with random buffer pointer, because buffer size is set to 0 (assume here not used non-cached io, and serial device not require special buffer align).

Comment: i be say next - if we check for `buffer.empty()` - we can not call `ReadFile` at all in this case, simply return 0. or pass nullptr in place buffer (instead `&trash`)

Comment: Yes, `&trash` is being pedantic.  Passing `nullptr` would be fine.  But passing `buffer.data()` is risky, since it's also undefined if the vector is empty.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I tried your suggestion the analysis tool still reports an error. I think i will just suppress it.

Comment: @rafael gonzalez:  Can you share which analysis tool you're using?  We're all just guessing without a way to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy HP fortify.